# A* Search for Maze - Infinite Loop When Path does not Exist - Python

Tags: python, infinite-loop, a-star

I am trying to implement an A-star search algorithm to find a path in a square maze from (0,0) to (dimension - 1, dimension - 1). My algorithm returns the correct path when it exists; however, if there is no path, then it runs in an infinite loop. How do I fix this? For now, I've put a condition to run if the length of the open list exceeds (dimension ^ 4), but this is obviously not a permanent fix. I am using Python 3.7.3.

```
import numpy as np

class node():

def __init__(self, parent=None, location=None):
    self.parent = parent
    self.location = location

    self.g = float(0)
    self.h = float(0)
    self.f = float(0)

#returns euclidean distance between two nodes
#takes the locations/tuples of two nodes as arguments
#works properly
def euclidean_distance(node_1, node_2):
    return float((((node_2[1] - node_1[1])**2) + ((node_2[0] - node_1[0])**2))**0.5)

#to make extracting the value at a given location in the maze easier
#takes the maze and two integers as arguments
def get_value(maze, a, b):
    return maze[a][b]

def out_of_bounds(a, b, dim):
    return (a < 0 or a >= dim) or (b < 0 or b >= dim)

#Euclidean A* Search, takes the maze and dimension as arguments
def a_star_euclidean(maze, dim):
    #initializing start node and end node
    start = node(None, (0,0))
    end = node(None, (dim-1, dim-1))

    #initializing open list and closed list
    open_list = []
    closed_list = []
    open_list.append(start)

    while len(open_list) > 0:

        #assigning currentNode
        currentNode = open_list[0]
        currentNode_index = 0

        #current location
        for index, item in enumerate(open_list):
            if item.f < currentNode.f:
                currentNode = item
                currentNode_index = index

        #(currentNode.location)

        row = currentNode.location[0]
        column = currentNode.location[1]

        #updating open list and closed list
        open_list.pop(currentNode_index)
        closed_list.append(currentNode)

        #in case goal node is already reached
        if currentNode.location == end.location:
            path = []
            current = currentNode
            while current is not None:
                path.append(current.location)
                current = current.parent
            #return path[::-1] #returning the path from start to end
            path.reverse()
            return path
        else:
            closed_list.append(currentNode)

        #generating childs
        child_locations = [(row+1, column), (row-1, column), (row, column+1), (row, column-1)]
        #print(child_locations)
        child_nodes = [node(currentNode, location) for location in child_locations]
        #print(child_nodes)

        for child in child_nodes:
            #declaring row and column variables for child nodes
            child_row = int(child.location[0])
            child_column = int(child.location[1])

            if not out_of_bounds(child_row, child_column, dim):

                # Child is on the closed list
                if child in open_list:
                    continue

                #computing g(n), h(n), f(n)
                child.g = float(currentNode.g + 1)
                child.h = float(euclidean_distance(child.location, end.location))
                child.f = float(child.g + child.h)

                #child is in open list
                if child in closed_list:
                    continue

                if get_value(maze, child_row, child_column) == 0:
                    open_list.append(child)
                else:
                    continue

            else:
                continue

        #if (len(open_list) > dim**4): #b^d worst case
            #return None

def main():
    maze = []
    dim = int(input("Enter the dimension of the game: "))
    print(dim)
    for row in range(dim):
        maze.append([])
        for column in range(dim):
            maze[row].append(int(np.random.binomial(1, 0.3, 1)))
    maze[0][0] = 0
    maze[dim-1][dim-1] = 0
    print(maze)
    print("----------")
    print(a_star_euclidean(maze,dim))

    #print(euclidean_distance((1,1), (2,2)))

main()
```

Comment: Is your `closed_list` being updated correctly? The search should exhaust all possible states and terminate. Is `child in closed_list` ever true?

Comment: So I thought it was, because I am appending currentNode to the closed list and I have the continue statement if child is in closed. @Dominic D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that `child in closed_list` is never true, because you haven't overriden the `__eq__` operator of the node class. Because of this, python doesn't know how to compare two instances of the node class, so falls back to comparing if they are references to the same object in memory, otherwise it returns false. So two nodes are never equal when searching through `closed_list`.

Try defining the `__eq__` operator for the node class like so. You can change the comparison to include other properties as you need.

```py
class node():
    def __init__(self, parent=None, location=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.location = location

        self.g = float(0)
        self.h = float(0)
        self.f = float(0)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.location == other.location
```